# Passing const object by reference issue

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

Suppose we have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Person{
public:
    Person(int age);
    int get_a();
private:
    int a;
};

Person::Person(int age)
{
    a = age;
}

int Person::get_a()
{
    return a;
}

void Show_Age(Person P)
{
    std::cout<<P.get_a()<<std::endl;
}

int main() {

    Person P(10);
    Show_Age(P);
    return 0;
}
```

Now suppose we have a heavy object, we should pass Person by reference, so we proceed:

```
void Show_Age(Person &P)
{
    std::cout<<P.get_a()<<std::endl;
}
```

There isn't a problem, but a good observation is P should be const, we try with it:

```
void Show_Age(const Person &P)
{
    std::cout<<P.get_a()<<std::endl;
}
```

A compiler failure:

```
error: passing ‘const Person’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Person::get_a()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Why don't you make `Show_Age` a member function?

Comment: Because it is a test function, actually I've got another class and a function that use get functions, so inside the class I have got a vector, so I need to pass an object by reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should mark `get_a` `const` in order for this to compile:

```
class Person{
public:
    Person(int age);
    int get_a() const;
private:
    int a;
};

int Person::get_a() const
{
    return a;
}
```

Doing so tells the compiler that the member function does not modify the state of the object, making it compatible with `const` pointers and references.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark `Person::get_a` as being constant as well:

```
class Person
{
    // ...

    int get_a() const;

    // ...
};
```

This tells the compiler that `get_a` does not modify the object.

Answer (score 1):

Const correct-ness is viral, and you should start from the inner out (i.e. each class should mark the member functions that don't modify the object as `const`, allowing callers to use them on const objects (or references to const objects).

Comment: Thank you, it's a good advice. Let me see, you're advising me: I should have got overloaded get functions for allowing users of the class use correctly the class as they wish?

Comment: @facunvd: In a slightly more generic sense, we are not talking about overloads, but rather each function. A function that does not modify the state of the object should be `const` (it **is** const, but you should tag it as such). Adding the `const` keyword means that the compiler knows as much as you do: `get_a` will not modify the object. Without it, the compiler does not know it and won't allow you to call the function on a const object.